# How does the hash match when the salt is generated randomly in password_hash?

Tags: php, hash, password-hash

How does this hashing decryption works when the salt is generated randomly by default. In my perceptions it seems something like this:

```
password_hash(random_salt1+pw) != password_hash(random_salt2+pw)
```

How does password_verify(random_salt2+pw) knows the original salt to decode when it's generated randomly?

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: It reruns the hash using the same parameters and if that matches the old hash BINGO. If you look at the output from `password_hash()` all the parameters are there in the resulting hash

Comment: Also `password_hash()` explicitly says DONT ADD YOUR OWN HASH. It generates a strong hash internally. A much better one that you are likely to create for yourself

Comment: Are you sure it isn't 
`password_hash(random_salt+pw1) != password_hash(random_salt+pw2)`? Because by definition, if the salts are different, the hashes will (statistically) never match.

Comment: ___From the manual of all places___ The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

Comment: ___Also from the manual___ Warning

The salt option is deprecated. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default. ___As of PHP 8.0.0, an explicitly given salt is ignored.___

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. It gave me a headache, how does it know the salt when it's generated randomly. It turns out it's included in the hash output. And I was talking about salt generated by default that's why I said in my perception.

Comment: Why not put all this in an answer so I validate it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It reruns the hash routine on the new text (password) using the parameters it placed in the hash and if that matches the old hash BINGO.

If you look at the output from password_hash() all the parameters are there in the resulting hash

See example

```
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_ARGON2I);
echo password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_ARGON2ID);
```

RESULTS

```
$2y$10$nbX83VUlyVstPCckavcJy.wQ84i8/cmBD/oeDV/zWrHXkuG6t/9fy
$argon2i$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$QlQ4emNEb1UxR1JiTG5Ddw$vw4HeiM9CEo8c2KNUslpC7qpH9M9Lo+WxBhX0UPp4oo
$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$U1loZThCYWtXcnpYWWV3NA$52eO0Ig9a1/pwqK3NPeNxwQpRuml36pjN2UN5BaGVGo
```

Notice that even if you use the same password (text string) you will not get the same hash from `password_hash()`, this is because the salt is randomly generated as part of the hashing process.

> Also `password_hash()` explicitly says DONT ADD YOUR OWN HASH. It generates a strong hash internally. A much better one that you are likely to create for yourself

> *From the manual* of all places The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

> *Also from the manual* Warning The salt option is deprecated. It is now preferred to simply use the salt that is generated by default. As of PHP 8.0.0, an explicitly given salt is ignored.

See this [for more information about how the hash is made up](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)